# ionic3 datetime - eventlistener for 'done'

Tags: angular, ionic3, event-listener

Hi is there a event for capture when the user has finished selecting a value? In the Ionic Docs there is only one listed for cancellation

ionCancel

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{"DURATION" | translate}} [min]</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime (change??)="done()" displayFormat="mm" minuteValues="15,20,25,30,45" [(ngModel)]="durationMinutes"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Did you tried `(ngModelChange)="done()"` not sure it will help you or not :)

Comment: thanks a ton! I was just starting to look if i could hook onto the ngModel!!

Comment: Great! Glad to know that helped :p

Comment: @PankajParkar could you please add an answer with that information? It may come in handy for other SO users, and that way we can also mark it as the accepted answer and close this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: @sebaferreras thanks mate, I added the answer, cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to look in for any output event here, you could use `(ngModelChange)` event binding, which will get called as soon as `ngModel`(durationMinutes) value gets changed.

```
<ion-datetime
  displayFormat="mm" 
  minuteValues="15,20,25,30,45" 
  [(ngModel)]="durationMinutes"
  (ngModelChange)="done()">
</ion-datetime>
```

You could also use `(ionChange)="done()` inspite of `ngModelChange` event

Comment: (ionChange)="done()" works perfectly as (ngModelChange)="done()" return last selected value

Comment: @UmarRasheed thanks, I updated answer with the same information.